# Vue 3 "v-model" with checkboxes but the data is "1" or "0" not "true" or "false"

Tags: vue.js, checkbox, v-model

Because of some reason on the backend, they use 0 or 1 and not false or true for booleans.

So, when I try to use the boolean data from API, TS complains:

```
// settings.crawl_on outputs 0 or 1
<input
 v-model=“settings.crawl_on”
 type="checkbox"
/>
```

I tried adding the below code it doesn't work either:

```
true-value="1"
false-value="0"
```

TS says:

> (property) InputHTMLAttributes.checked?: any[] | Set | Booleanish
> Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'any[] | Set |
> Booleanish'.ts(2322)runtime-dom.d.ts(629, 3): The expected type comes from property 'checked' which is declared here on type
> 'ElementAttrs'

Is there a way to override this or what is the correct use?

Comment: You can provide a computed with getter and setter that converts numbers to/from booleans

Answer (score 7):

Upgraded from Vue 2 to Vue 3, got same issue. This didn't work:

```
true-value="1"
false-value="0"
```

But this works:

```
:true-value="1"
:false-value="0"
```

Comment: Stuff like this just drives me up the wall with Vue... solved my problem though- thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Because static html attributes values are 'String' type. And you are expecting 'Integers'.
So, when you use "v-bind:" making attributes dynamic values, you are sending 'Integers'

```
true-value="1" <-- string 
true-value="1" <-- integer
:true-value="'1'" <-- string
```

Answer (score 0):

For input `type="checkbox"`, `0` will be same as `false` and `1` will be same as `true`.

Hence, `settings.crawl_on = 1` will be same as `settings.crawl_on = true`.

I checked same with `TypeScript` as well as `JavaScript` and it's working fine in both the languages.

Demo **:**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    settings: {
        crawl_on: 1
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <input
         v-model="settings.crawl_on"
         type="checkbox"
         />
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. My bad. I forgot to mention it is a Vue3 app and it complains.

Comment: But this is not related to `Vue` version. It will work in both the cases.